# Extensions for android browsers

Tags: android, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, mozilla, firefox-addon-sdk

Recently I have been thinking about extensions/add-ons on android Devices. I have read somewhere that extensions don't work on android chrome. Is it true? Secondly, how can I develop extensions for android firefox ?Does the extensions build using sdk-addon for desktop browser will work for android devices?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a browser on android accepting extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185882/is-there-a-browser-on-android-accepting-extensions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: if you develop a Firefox add-on with the add-on SDK, it will work on the Firefox Android browser. Not all the APIs are supported, and you need to create a separate build of the add-on. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Mobile_development for the details.

Answer (score 1):

You have heard correct. Extensions do not work on Chrome.

*Does Chrome for Android support apps and extensions?
Chrome apps and extensions are currently not supported on Chrome for Android. We have no plans to announce at this time.*
[See Documentation here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/faq)

Comment: Thanks a lot. what about mozilla firefox?